# Is Star Wars: The High Republic character Lourna Dee a reference to novel/character Lorna Doone?

Tags: star-wars, novel, reference

I have just recently finished reading the first Star Wars novel set in the new High Republic, [*Light of the Jedi*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_High_Republic:_Light_of_the_Jedi).

One of the villainous female characters is named Lourna Dee, which sounds a lot like Lorna D., something that could be close to [Lorna Doone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorna_Doone).

*Is the character Lourna Dee in *Light of the Jedi* meant to be reference to the book and/or character Lorna Doone?*

Why else do I think this:

**Mild Light of the Jedi Spoilers Ahead!**

- Lourna Dee is a member in a leadership position of the Nihil, a new  enemy that thrives off of chaos (nihilism) and it isn't beyond any
  member of the Nihil to consider other members expendable. The opening
  act of *Lorna Doone* begins when a farmer is killed by one of the
  members of the Doone clan. *Light of the Jedi* fixates, at first, on a
  system called Hetzel, which is a huge agriculture system for the
  entire outer rim. Farming and/or a serious plight to look at farmers,
  is theme of the both works.
- The opening of *Lorna Doone* goes over "The Great Winter". The first  part of *Light of the Jedi* counts down in POV chapters to an
  event  that is called, "The Great Disaster".
- While author RD Blackmoore didn't consider his novel a history novel,  but instead a romance, it's considered by many to be both
  with some siting Gothic elements, including a Gothic villain. *Light of Jedi* is mostly a fictional-universe history novel introducing new characters in a new era, but it has a surprisingly Gothic Villain (The Eye of the Nihil) at it's center and has light romance instead of heavy.
- Blackmoore believed he relied on style of "phonologic" speech. While  *Light of the Jedi* doesn't necessary play on dialect, it does
  have very distinct characters and a very layered phonologic style or sense of word play and other
  distinct  juxtapositions or imagery. One villainous character, for
  instance, is named Pan Eyta and there is a prestigious Republic
  medical ship named Pancea, and ironically, that ship is uniquely
  contrasted to another ship, The Gaze Electric (for reasons I can not say because it's a huge spoiler), while Pan Eyta has the
  taste of the elite in the Republic and seems counter to the rest of the Nihil.
- As mentioned, *Lorna Doone* is lightly considered a Gothic Victorian novel and The Gilded Age exists in parallel across the pound in
  America in this era. The High Republic is also set during a "golden
  age" similar  to a kind of Gilded Age or Renaissance where the outer Rim is kind of like an great frontier the Republic is tying to expand into, especially when we know the Republic will begin to decline and ultimately fall (200 years later) during the events of The Skywalker Saga.

Comment: Given Charles Soule's seeming obsession with feminist literature and Hispanic culture, it's more likely a reference to Lorna Dee Cervantes. I cant find any direct evidence though.

Comment: or maybe Soule likes shortbread cookies

Comment: @Valorum If parallels could be made between her work and his, I would gladly take it as an answer. I don't know if this could be called a feminist work since it has a diverse cast and Lourna Dee does some pretty despicable things. Soule is also good at playing up the Gothic (Darth Vader Darth Lord of the Sith) and I would think would be no stranger to well-known literature either. I just felt like there were too many coincidences to ignore.

Comment: @NKCampbell Ha! No, unlike the Mandalorian, cookies are sorely lacking in the High Republic! ;)

Comment: I've twitted at the author to ask the question. I'm not expecting an answer to be forthcoming, but still...

Comment: @Valorum Cool! I hope you get a response!

Comment: @DarthLocke - I very much doubt it. Star Wars authors don't usually chat about their works.

Comment: True, but Ron Howard or someone at Lucasfilm did release an easter egg list for 'Solo', which included my hunch that Lady Proxima was homage to Bram Stoker's Lair of the White Worm, so you never know...

Comment: Also there have been a lot of SW author interviews over the years and THR group already has quite a few, they just don't always talk about their influences. However one new character not yet introduced, is visually based on "young" Matthew McConaughey LOL. So they have been a bit more forthcoming in order to promote this whole giant book (and TV series) thing...